# How can I plot 3D function in r?

Tags: r, plot

I have a function in 3D - let's say De Jong function:

```
fdejong <- function (x, y) {
   return (x^2 + y^2)
}
```

How can I draw it's plot in 3D? I want to achieve an effect similar to this from wikipedia:

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sphere_function_in_3D.pdf]

Comment: see the `curve3d()` function from the `emdbook` package.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/11875941/3d-equivalent-of-the-curve-function-in-r/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the Lattice `wireframe` function. (Using @user1020027's data)

```
fdejong <- function (x, y) {
   return (x^2 + y^2)
}

x <- seq(-10, 10, length= 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, fdejong)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1

require(lattice)
wireframe(z, drape=T, col.regions=rainbow(100))
```

[image: lattice wireframe color plot]

Answer (score 9):

try this :

```
fdejong <- function (x, y) {
   return (x^2 + y^2)
}


x <- seq(-10, 10, length= 30)
y <- x
z <- outer(x, y, fdejong)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1
op <- par(bg = "white")
persp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
```

[image: fdejong persp plot]

Comment: It's almost what I want, but is it any way to color it like that plot in wikipedia (color depend on the function value)?

Comment: +1 for using the base function!!