# Evaluating and plotting a 3d log-likelihood function using R

Tags: r, function, plot

My objective is to evaluate and to plot the following log-likelihood function with two parameters:

```
set.seed(123)
N = 100
x = 4*rnorm(N)
y = 0.8*x + 2*rnorm(N);

LogL <- function(param,x,y,N){
        beta = param[1]
        sigma2 = param[2]
        LogLikelihood =  -N/2*log(2*pi*sigma2) - sum( (y - beta*x)^2 / (2*sigma2) ) }
```

I've tried using 'outer' in order to use 'wireframe' as in the following thread:

[How can I plot 3D function in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065615/how-can-i-plot-3d-function-in-r/24065697)

but without success:

```
param1 <- seq(-2, 2, length= 30)
param2 <- seq(0.1, 4, length= 30)
values1 <- matrix(c(param1,param2),30)
z <- outer(values1, x=x,y=y,N=N, LogL)
```

How can I use 'outer' properly in this case? Is there any other alternative to evaluate and to plot the function 'LogL'?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is that `outer()` needs to have the two arguments to `LogL()` as separate vectors, which means rewriting your function to use the two arguments instead of one length 2 argument that you unpack. In addition, (from ?outer)

> Each will be extended by rep to length the products of the lengths of X and Y before FUN is called.

so the function needs to deal with ALL the possible values of X and Y in a single call. There's probably a better way to do this, but in the interest of simplicity, I used a `for()` loop to loop over the different values of X and Y.

```r
set.seed(123)
N = 100
x = 4*rnorm(N)
y = 0.8*x + 2*rnorm(N);

LogL <- function(param1, param2, x, y, N){
  beta = param1
  sigma2 = param2
  LogLikelihood = vector("numeric",length(beta))
  for (i in 1:length(beta)){
    LogLikelihood[i] = -N/2*log(2*pi*sigma2[i]) - sum( (y - beta[i]*x)^2 / (2*sigma2[i]) )
  }
  return(LogLikelihood)
}

param1 <- seq(-2, 2, length= 30)
names(param1) <- param1
param2 <- seq(0.1, 4, length= 30)
names(param2) <- param2


z <- outer(X = param1, Y = param2, FUN = LogL, N = N, x = x, y = y)

require(lattice)
#> Loading required package: lattice
wireframe(z, drape=T, col.regions=rainbow(100))
```

[image]

```r
# test it out
LogL(param1[3], param2[3],  x = x, y = y, N = N)
#> [1] -11768.37

z[3,3]
#> [1] -11768.37
```

and that works.

Created on 2018-03-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: So, the problem was in the function, interesting. Thank you.

Comment: After analyzing the results, I realized that `outer()` does not evaluate properly the function, the results of plotting the log-likelihood look unusual in `wireframe(z, drape=T, col.regions=rainbow(100))`. How to formulate it correctly?

Comment: Ah, I see - the function isn't properly vectorized. It is getting the parameters as vectors.